# Counterexample to Glivenko's theorem in predicate logic

Tags: predicate-logic, intuitionistic-logic

I read everywhere that Glivenko's double negation translation does not generalise to predicate logic. In other words, this means that for some predicate formula $\phi$ we have $\vdash\phi$ classically while $\not\vdash\lnot\lnot\phi$ intuitionistically. Most literature I find skips this point and continues showing that the Gödel-Gentzen translation does work in intuitionistic predicate logic.

Could anyone give an example of such a $\phi$ that is classically valid while $\lnot\lnot\phi$ is not provable intuitionistically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA161), Springer (5th ed - 2013), page 161.

Gödel's transaltion has (for the non-trivial cases) :

> $\varphi^G := \lnot \lnot \varphi$, for $\varphi$ atomic
>
> $(\varphi \lor \psi)^G := \lnot (\lnot \varphi^G \land \lnot \psi^G)$
>
> $(\exists x \ \varphi(x))^G := \lnot \forall x \lnot \ \varphi^G(x)$.

The relation between classical derivability $(\vdash_C$) and intuitionistic derivability ($\vdash_I$) is:

> $\Gamma \vdash_c \varphi \ $ **iff** $ \ \Gamma^G \vdash_I \varphi^G$.

We have to note the special role of $∨$ and $∃$ in intuitionistic logic. This is underlined by the following result.

A formula $\varphi$ is called *negative* if atoms occur only negated, and it does not contain $\lor$ or $\exists$. In this case we have:

> $\vdash_C \varphi$ **iff** $\vdash_I \varphi$, for *negative* $\varphi$.

For propositional logic we have a "stronger" result:

> *Glivenko’s Theorem*: $\vdash_C \varphi$ iff $\vdash_I ¬¬ \varphi$.

An example of "double negation" formula that is not derivable in intuitionistic logic is:

> $\lnot \lnot \forall x \ (A(x) \lor \lnot A(x))$.

See Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=QrdEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA142), Cambridge UP (2013), page 142, for the proof on its unprovability in intuitionistic predicate calculus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is mainly how I could see that a formula like $\lnot\lnot\forall x(P(x)\lor\lnot P(x))$ is not provable in IL?

Comment: @Kaj - "standard procedure": a counterexample based on Kripke models.

Comment: @Kaj Another possible counterexample to show $\lnot\lnot \forall x (P(x) \vee \lnot P(x))$ is not provable in IL would be to give a topos where $\forall p : \Omega, p \lor \lnot p$ evaluates to $\bot$, and therefore $\lnot\lnot \forall p : \Omega, p \lor \lnot p$ also evaluates to $\bot$.  One such topos is the category of sheaves on $\mathbb{R}$.