# doubly negated intuitionistic formulas

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, intuitionistic-logic, nonclassical-logic

What is an example of some doubly negated statement in intuitionistic logic that is not equivalent to its classical version?

Some background: for every statement $P$ we can find a classically equivalent statement $Q$ that is valid classically iff it's valid intuitionistically. When $P$ does not have quantifiers, you can take $Q$ to be $\lnot \lnot P$. In general it's a bit harder.

So there are some statements $P$ such that $\lnot \lnot P$ is classically valid but not intuitionistically valid. What's an explicit example?

I guess in these situations you can add $\lnot P$ as an axiom and not arrive at a contradiction intuitionistically, but there would be a classical contradiction.

For example, $$\lnot \lnot \forall x\ (x=0 \lor x\ne 0)$$ in the real numbers might work, because its negation is
$$\lnot \forall x\ (x=0 \lor x \ne 0)$$ which is not contradictory intuitionistically, I think. How do you prove that? Or what's another example if this one does not work?

---

Edited: to make my question clearer. I will use sequent calculus as in the current answer, so $LJ$ is the intuitionistic system and $LK$ is the classical one.

For any formula  $P,$ let $P^{\lnot\lnot}$ be a formula that is classically equivalent to $P$ and such that $\newcommand\intui{\vdash^{LJ}} \newcommand\classi{\vdash^{LK}} \intui P^{\lnot \lnot}$ iff $\classi P^{\lnot \lnot}$.

For simple formulas, $P^{\lnot\lnot}$ is just $\lnot \lnot P.$ For more complex formulas the double negation outside is not enough. So it is possible to have a formula $P$ with $\classi P$ but not $\intui \lnot \lnot P$. Thus $\lnot P$ is consistent intuitionistically, but not classically.

I was looking for an example of such $P$. In order to do that, I wanted a not purely logical example, so I searched inside a theory $\Gamma$, thinking that $\Gamma \classi P$ iff $\Gamma \intui P^{\lnot \lnot}.$ I was corrected (see answer below), because $\Gamma$ must also be changed. Even then, one can find examples of theories where $\Gamma \classi P$ but not $\Gamma \intui \lnot \lnot P$ (one is my example with a theory of the real numbers that allows it, according to the answer; I will have to study that).

In that case $\Gamma, \lnot P$ is **consistent intuitionistically but not classically**, and I wanted to know how to interpret that, with some example.

Comment: Related: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210126/counterexample-to-glivenkos-theorem-in-predicate-logic?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

You ask multiple different questions. I will go through them instance-by-instance. Since I wasn't sure what you mean by the word *valid* (as in when you say that some statement is "classically valid"): I interpreted it as provability in the logic in question under some implicitly specified theory. If you meant something else, let me know.

> What is an example of some doubly negated statement in intuitionistic logic that is not equivalent to its classical version?

Clearly, every double-negated sentence is classically equivalent to its non-double-negated version. However, any non-provable instance of the Law of Excluded Middle yields an example of a double-negated sentence that the intuitionistic theory in question won't prove equivalent to its classical version.

For example, let $P(x)$ denote "*$x$ codes a proof of a contradiction in [Heyting arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_arithmetic)*". Then, by [Gödel's incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem), if Heyting arithmetic is $\omega$-consistent, it fails to prove both $\exists x. P(x)$ and $\neg \exists x. P(x)$. Since Heyting arithmetic has the disjunction property, it won't prove $\exists x. P(x) \vee \neg \exists x.P(x)$ either.

However, Heyting arithmetic does prove $\neg\neg ((\exists x. P(x)) \vee \neg \exists x. P(x))$. Indeed, $\neg \neg (A \vee \neg A)$ constitutes an intuitionistic tautology for any sentence $A$. The proof goes as follows. Since $A \rightarrow (A \vee \neg A)$ and $\neg A \rightarrow (A \vee \neg A)$ both hold, the contrapositives $\neg (A \vee \neg A) \rightarrow \neg A$ and $\neg (A \vee \neg A) \rightarrow \neg\neg A$ hold as well. So $\neg (A \vee \neg A)$ implies a contradiction, and consequently $\neg \neg (A \vee \neg A)$ holds.

> Some background: for every statement P we can find a classically equivalent statement Q that is valid classically iff it's valid intuitionistically.

The [double-negation translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation#First-order_logic) gives us a sentence $S^{\neg\neg}$ so that $S \leftrightarrow S^{\neg\neg}$ holds in classical logic, and $\Gamma \vdash_{LK} S$ in classical logic precisely if $\Gamma^{\neg\neg} \vdash_{LJ} S^{\neg\neg}$ in intuitionisitic logic.

Alas, intuitionistically the theory $\Gamma^{\neg\neg}$ may have very little to do with the theory $\Gamma$. For example, if $\Gamma$ contains axioms of the form $(\forall x. L(x)) \rightarrow Q$ for atomic predicates $L,Q$, these will get translated in $\Gamma^{\neg\neg}$ as $(\forall x. \neg\neg L(x)) \rightarrow \neg\neg Q$. And the former need not imply the latter intuitionistically, nor does the latter need to imply the former intuitionistically.

> So there are some statements P such that ¬¬P is classically valid but not intuitionistically valid.

Again, I'm not quite sure what you mean by *valid* here.

If you can find $P$ such that $\Gamma$ entails $\neg\neg P$ classically, but not intuitionistically, then you can dispense with the double-negation altogether: $\Gamma$ entails $P$ classically (since $P \leftrightarrow \neg\neg P$ holds classically), and $\Gamma$ does not entail $P$ intuitionistically (since $P \rightarrow \neg\neg P$ holds intuitionistically).

Really, you should say: there may be some statements $P$ such that $P$ is classically valid ($\Gamma \vdash_{LK} P$?) but not intuitionistically valid ($\Gamma \not\vdash_{LJ} P$?).

> I guess in these situations you can add ¬P as an axiom and not arrive at a contradiction intuitionistically, but there would be a classical contradiction.

You seem to be using an inference along the following lines: if $\Gamma \vdash_{LK} P$ but $\Gamma \not\vdash_{LJ} P$, then $\Gamma \cup \{ \neg P \}$ is consistent in intuitionistic logic. This kind of reasoning does not work. For example, the empty theory satisfies $\vdash_{LK} A \vee \neg A$ for any formula $A$, but of course the theory $\{\neg (A \vee \neg A)\}$ is inconsistent even in intuitionistic logic.

That said, while your reasoning to establish it was not valid, the phenomenon does happen. For example, the theory $\{ \neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \}$ in the language consisting of one predicate symbol $M$ is consistent intuitionistically. One can show this either by constructing a model (such as a Heyting-valued model, or a Kripke model, or a topological model), or explain by a combinatorial argument why $\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash \bot$ has no cut-free proof tree in the intuitionistic [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#The_system_LK) **LJ**. I'll do the latter.

We define a *rut* as a sequent of one of the following 5 forms:

1. $M(t_1),M(t_2),\dots,M(t_n),\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x),\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x), \dots, \neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash \bot$,
2. $M(t_1),M(t_2),\dots,M(t_n),\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x),\dots, \neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash M(s)$,
3. $M(t_1),M(t_2),\dots,M(t_n),\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x), \dots, \neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash \neg M(s)$
4. $M(t_1),M(t_2),\dots,M(t_n),\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x), \dots, \neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash M(s) \vee \neg M(s)$
5. $M(t_1),M(t_2),\dots,M(t_n),\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x), \dots, \neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x)$

such that $s \not\in \{t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n\}$.

Now, we have the following simple observations:

1. If you apply a rule of the intuitionistic sequent calculus **LJ** to a rut, then you get another rut. For example, if you have $M(t_1),\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x)$, and you apply the $\forall R$ rule, then you end up with $M(t_1),\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash M(s) \vee \neg M(s)$ for some $s \neq t_1$.
2. A rut cannot conclude any branch of a proof. To conclude a branch, you'd have to use an axiom rule, but that requires the same formula to occur on both the left and the right of the turnstile. This clearly never happens in a rut.

These together imply that a rut has no intuitionistic proof: to conclude the proof, we'd somehow have to get out of the rut (2), but we cannot do that using intuitionistic rules (1).

Since $\neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \vdash \bot$ is a rut, it also has no intuitionistic proof, so the theory $\{ \neg \forall x. M(x) \vee \neg M(x) \}$ in the language consisting of one predicate symbol $M$ is consistent intuitionistically. It is of course not consistent classically (and as you'd expect, contraction on the right $CR$, a rule that the intuitionistic calculus **LJ** does not contain, but the classical calculus **LK** does contain, immediately yields a non-rut from a rut).

> How do you prove that [$\neg \forall x. x = 0 \vee \neg x = 0$ is not contradictory for intuitionistic real numbers]?

I don't know whether this can happen for intuitionistic (say Dedekind) reals. But there are contexts where it happens: $\neg \forall x. x = 0 \vee \neg x = 0$ is satisfied e.g. by the real line of Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis. A direct combinatorial proof showing the consistency of Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis, resembling the one above, would be prohibitively difficult to write down. Instead, you usually have to construct a model where the interpretation of $\neg \forall x. x = 0 \vee \neg x = 0$ actually holds. The first chapter of [Moerdijk-Reyes](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4143-8) will give you an idea of how it's done.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very thorough! I will append an edit to my question to make the main one clear, as I realize I wasn't very clear. You have answered it in the second half, anyway. I will have to read that chapter to understand it better

Comment: Hi Z., Could you please check the correctness of this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/397338/72694 ?  Since there is a comment complaining about it...  and it is an *accepted* answer...